# RegEX match if condition 1 exists but condition 2 does not RegEX

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to build a regex for a data loss prevention policy in which we need to match long form birth dates while avoiding a forwarded Sent box.

This is what I have so far, but it is not working the way I had hoped. I am relatively new to regex. Please excuse any poor form.

`(?i)(?!Sent:)\b(dob|date of birth|birth\s?date|birthday|born|d\.o\.b)\b\D{0,500}\b(jan|january|feb|february|mar|march|apr|april|may|jun|june|jul|july|aug|august|sep|sept|september|oct|october|nov|november|dec|december)\b\D{0,5}\b(\d{1,2})\D{0,20}(\d{2,4})\b`

The idea is IF `Sent:' is not present AND (dob|date of birth|birth\s?date|birthday|born|d\.o\.b)` is, THEN look for the above format within 500 characters of said word match.

for example: 
if an email is sent with--

```
Date of Birth 

From: 
Sent: Tuesday, September 26, 2017 9:19 AM
To: ''
Subject: FW: Routing Number Test
```

--I want the regex to NOT match the date after the `Sent:`

Is it even possible to match a using a double condition? Am I trying to accomplish something that regex is not meant for?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you could make it a little more clear, but I'm not quite sure I understand. Also, I'd consider this regex instead of your existing one: `(?!Sent:)\b(dob|date\s*of\s*birth|birth\s*date|birthday|born|d\.o\.b)\b\D{0,500}\b(jan(?:uary)?|feb(?:ruary)?|mar(?:ch)?|apr(?:il)?|may|june?|july?|aug(?:ust)?|sep(?:tember|t)?|oct(?:ober)?|nov(?:ember)?|dec(?:ember)?)\b\D{0,5}\b(\d{1,2})\D{0,20}(\d{2,4})\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pushed the sent to after dob etc. so that sent and date will be ignored when they come together.

```
(?i)\b(dob|date of birth|birth\s?date|birthday|born|d.o.b)\b(?:(?!Sent:)\D){0,500}\b(jan|january|feb|february|mar|march|apr|april|may|jun|june|jul|july|aug|august|sep|sept|september|oct|october|nov|november|dec|december)\b\D{0,5}\b(\d{1,2})\D{0,20}(\d{2,4})\b
```

Find the regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/wUt2l8/2).

Only change made is the below:

`(?:(?!Sent:)\D){0,500}`  -- Match 0 to 500 non-digit  characters only if they are not followed by `sent:`

Although the regex could be made a bit more efficient, I only solved your double condition issue at the moment.

Comment: @TannerDiercks removed the info, sorry to overlook that earlier!